# why is run.sh in alpha geometry not working?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

i want to install alpha geometry on my mac using the discord link https://github.com/google-deepmind/alphageometry and i am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text==2.13.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text==2.13.0
```

please explain it in easy to understand terms, because i am not that good in it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Python 3.10,Install it and modify the run.sh:

```
virtualenv -p python3.10 .
```

In the requirements.txt they said This file is autogenerated by pip-compile with Python 3.10.

However the alphageometry doesn't work well in my machine.The Error Info is

```
ERROR: In --require-hashes mode,all requirements must...etils[epath] from https://.../etils-1.6.0-py3-none-any-whl (from array-record...)
```

and you can try modify the run.sh:

```
pip install -r requirements.in
```